# Loop through a table based on multiple conditions

Tags: sql, loops

Students table

```
student_id  student_name
1           John
2           Mary
```

Grades table

```
student_id   year   grade_level  school        Course    Mark
  1          2015    10          Smith High     Algebra   95
  1          2015    10          Smith High     English   96
  1          2016    11          Smith High     Geometry  85
  1          2016    11          Smith High     Science   88
  2          2015    10          Smith High     Algebra   98
  2          2015    10          Smith High     English   93
  2          2016    11          Smith High     Geometry  97
  2          2016    11          Smith High     Science   86
```

I'm trying to show results for each year and what class a student took with the grade.

So the final output i'm looking for is something like:

```
[student_id1] [year1] [grade1] [school1]
[course1] [mark1]
[course2] [mark2]
[course3] [mark3]...
[student_id1] [year2] [grade2] [school1]
[course1] [mark1]
[course2] [mark2]
[course3] [mark3]...
[student_id2] [year1] [grade1] [school1]
[course1] [mark1]
[course2] [mark2]
[course3] [mark3]...
```

This would all go in one column/row.  So in this particular example, this would be my result:

```
1 2015 10 Smith High 
Algebra 95
English 96
1 2016 11 Smith High 
Geometry 85
Science 88
2 2015 10 Smith High 
Algebra 98
English 93
2 2016 11 Smith High 
Geometry 97
Science 86
```

So anytime a student id, year, grade, or school name changes, I would have a line for that and loop through the classes taken within that group.  And all of this would be in one column/row.

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure how I can properly loop through course and grades for each group.  I'd appreciate it if I can be pointed in the right direction.

```
select s.student_id + '' + year + '' + grade_level + '' + school 
from students
join grades on students.student_id = grades.student_id
```

Comment: This would be achieved much easier by a report, rather than a query as you're basically trying to format your results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it in your SQL Enviromnment, it depends on the Database Management System you are using.

For example, if you are using Transact SQL you can try to look at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Generally this kind of loops and interactions are done in the programming language that is coupled with the SQL DB.

Anyway, you should look at Stored Procedures and Cursors if you really want to do this in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix presentation with retrieval of data from database tables. Looping through the resultset in sql can be achieved via cursor but that isn't adviced. You are better off by pulling the required data using two queries and later print it using a language of your choice.